# JavaScript objects/attributes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and been fiddling around with HTML5  element.

The thing is that I'm now using a library to help simplify the use of the canvas on a multitude of devices, including mobile, but I have now a question that is bugging me since it appears so simple yet I'm unable to find a solution. I do believe this might be a newbie mistake but here is the deal:

I have these 2 functions:

```
function drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(sX, sY);
    ctx.lineTo(eX, eY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    return { x: eX, y: eY };
}

function canvas() {
    var canvas = new Canvas ('canvas', 0, function () {
        this.clear();
        this.setAutoResize(true);
    });

    canvas.canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight;

    canvas.onTouchStart = function(start) {
        var sX; var sY;
        return {sX: start.clientX, sY: start.clientY};
    }

    canvas.onTouchEnd = function (end) {
        var eX; var eY;
        return {eX: end.clientX, eY: end.clientY};
    }

    // canvas.onTouchMove = drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY);
}
```

Not getting into too much detail, how will I be able to use the values returned by onTouchStart() and onTouchEnd() to pass the x,y positions into the drawLine function?

All I'm getting is values that are not defined and I'm really lost here..

UPDATE:

@Juan Mendes,

Thanks for your help, but that didn't seem to work either.

For a better understanding of the "backside" code, here is an example of the touchstart thing:

```
this.canvasElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    var touchCount = event.changedTouches.length;
    var touches = [];
    var touch = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < touchCount; i++) {
        touch = event.changedTouches[i];

        var touchInfo = {
            pageX : touch.pageX,
            pageY : touch.pageY,
            clientX : touch.clientX,
            clientY : touch.clientY,
            screenX : touch.screenX,
            screenY : touch.screenY,
            target : touch.target,
            identifier : touch.identifier
        };

    self.onTouchStart(touchInfo, i, touchCount, event);

    touches.push(touchInfo);

    self.previousTouchInfo[touch.identifier] = touchInfo;
    }

    if (touchCount == 1) {
        touch = event.changedTouches[0];

        var x = touch.clientX;
        var y = touch.clientY;

        if (self.touchEmulatesMouse) {
            self.mouse.x = x;
            self.mouse.y = y;
            self.mouse.left = true;

            if (self.layerParent != null) {
                self.layerParent.onMouseDown(x, y, 0);
            }

        self.onMouseDown(x, y, 0);
        }
        } else {
            self.onMultiTouchStart(touches, event);
        }
    }, false);

/* A bit more down the library code */
/**
* Called at the start of every touch start (including when multiple touches occured)
*
* The info object contains the folloring info:
* - pageX - X coordinate relative to the full page (includes scrolling)
* - pageY - Y coordinate relative to the full page (includes scrolling)
* - clientX - X coordinate of touch relative to the viewport (excludes scroll offset)
* - clientY - Y coordinate of touch relative to the viewport (excludes scroll offset)
* - screenX - X coordinate relative to the screen
* - screenY - Y coordinate relative to the screen
*
* @param {object} info Touch info
* @param {integer} index Touch index
* @param {integer} count The total number of active touches
* @param {object} event The actual touch event
*/
onTouchStart: function(info, index, count, event) {},
```

And I also changed my code to reflect your help, a few changes and also tried using the touchInfo param like this:

```
function createCanvas() {
var canvas = new Canvas ('canvas', 0, function () {
    this.clear();
    this.setAutoResize(true);
});

var cWidth = canvas.canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth;
var cHeight = canvas.canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight;

var startPoint = null;

function fill() {
    canvas.fillStyle = "black";
    canvas.fillRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
    canvas.beginPath();
}

// Draw a line on the canvas from (s)tart to (e)nd
function drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY) {
    canvas.beginPath()
    canvas.moveTo(sX, sY);
    canvas.lineTo(eX, eY);
    canvas.stroke();
    canvas.closePath();
    //return { x: eX, y: eY };
}

fill();

canvas.onTouchStart = function(start) {
    startPoint = {sX: this.clientX, sY: this.clientY};
}

canvas.onTouchEnd = function (end) {
    drawLine(startPoint.sX, startPoint.sY, this.clientX, this.clientY);
    // return {eX: end.clientX, eY: end.clientY};
}
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get around the problem. Turns out the library wasn't properly ended (yet) and I was also misusing the functions without getting any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what you're asking but hope this helps

I think what you need is something like the following

```
(function() {
// Save the startPoint so we can use it when the touch ends to draw the line
var startPoint;
canvas.onTouchStart = function(e) {
    // set the shared variable 
    startPoint = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
}

canvas.onTouchEnd = function (e) {
    drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, e.clientX, e.clientY);
}
})();
```

I think the name of the event is `ontouchstart`, not `onTouchStart`

Here's what I think your code should look like

```
function drawLine(sX, sY, eX, eY) {
    // Bad use of ctx global, you should pass it into the function so you can support
    // multiple contexts
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(sX, sY);
    ctx.lineTo(eX, eY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    // Kind of silly to return this object, the caller already passed it in
    // Should be used only if you need some kind of chaining, but
    // makes for a weird API
    return { x: eX, y: eY };
}

// Don't name a function and a variable the same thing, 
// you had canvas as a variable and as a function. 
// They didn't cause a problem, but it's just not pretty to look at
function createCanvas() {    
    var canvas = new Canvas('canvas', 0, function () {
        this.clear();
        this.setAutoResize(true);
    });

    canvas.canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight;


    // Save the startPoint so we can use it when the touch ends to draw the line
    var startPoint;
    // Correct spelling for ontouchstart
    canvas.ontouchstart = function(start) {
        // set the shared variable that will be used when they finish touching
        startPoint = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
    }

    // Draw the line
    canvas.ontouchend = function (e) {
        drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: Well, I'm going to try you advice. BTW, the onTouchStart is spelled that way because it's a library method. I'm using HTML Canvas Lib: http://html-canvas-lib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi @Juan. Thanks for your help. I've retouched the code a little bit but still didn't work. I've posted the new code in the next "answer" so, could you please take a took at it? Thanks

Comment: yup, I'm still getting undefined values. I've added the code modifications, on the original post. Also I noticed that there is a touchInfo variable on the library for each touch event, but even using those, I'm not getting any value returned, although the touchInfo variable has all the attributes I need..